# why int list is not getting converted in python 3.7 and above but works on python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Python 2.7 as below

```
>>> l1 =[1,2,3]
>>> for x in l1:
  str(x)


'1'
'2'
'3'
>>>
```

why in python 3.7 the int to str wont work as seen above in 2.7?

Python 3.7 as below

```
>>> l1[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for x in l1:print(str(x))
Traceback (mostrecentcalllast):File <pyshell#593>", line 2, in <module>
     print(str(x))
     TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is `l1[1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: Well it works for Python 3.6.1 and i think it should for 3.7 also.
Do you might have overwritten str by a custom type?

Answer (score 3):

This likely happened because you defined a variable `str` at some point earlier on:

```
>>> str = '3'
>>> str(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

You should avoid using the same names for variables as for built-in functions (like `str()`) as otherwise things like the above can happen.

Comment: It could also be `print` that was overwritten.

Comment: @KlausD.  `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`  - why should print be overridden? see question.

Comment: `'str' object` does not mean the object called `str` but of type `str`. If `print` is set to a string  and is called the same error is raised.

Comment: Thanks you so much everyone.  for your response.

Comment: l1=[1, 2, 3, 4]?

Comment: hi sheldore this was l1= [1, 2, 3, 4]. while posting it and removing some extra lines  = was deleted by mistake

Comment: Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> l1 =[1,2,3]
>>> for x in l1:
 str(x)

 
'1'
'2'
'3'

Comment: today i tested the above code and it worked.. not sure what went wrong yesterday